# Why does virtualenv create the environments with Python2.7 if I installed it using pip3?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I installed virtualenv using `sudo pip3 install virtualenv --upgrade`, and yet every time I create a new environment (`virtualenv test`) it's running python2.7...

I know I can create the env. via `virtualenv -p python3 test`, but I don't want to do that. Virtualenv states that the default interpreter is the interpreter that virtualenv was installed with, but that's not the case.

Any ideas?

PS: I am running on OSX, my default Python interpreter is Python2.7 but I made sure to install virtualenv with pip3.

Comment: The default interpreter mentioned in the docs is the one that is called when running `python` on your system. If both 2 and 3 are installed, its most likely 2.

Comment: If you have Python >= 3.3 you can simply use [venv](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/venv.html) and it should use Python 3.X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine, when I do this:

```
$ virtualenv[hit-tab-now-for-autocomplete]
virtualenv      virtualenv-2.7  virtualenv-3.4
```

So, I can simply do:

```
$ virtualenv-3.4 test
```